# How to close an entire task stack of activites?

Tags: android, android-activity, oauth, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo

I'm using the library [SocialLib](http://code.google.com/p/sociallib/) to add sharing functionality to my app. I'm having real issues with the oAuth callback.

I've created the following Activity to handle sharing:

```
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.SocialNetworkHelper;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.connectors.TwitterConnector;
import com.expertiseandroid.lib.sociallib.exceptions.NotAuthentifiedException;

public class ShareActivity extends Activity {

    protected final static String TAG = "ShareActivity";    
    private final Activity activity = this;

    public static final int SERVICE_TWITTER = 0;
    public static final int SERVICE_FACEBOOK = 1;
    public static final int SERVICE_LINKEDIN = 2;

    // twitter API
    protected static String TWITTER_KEY = "";
    protected static String TWITTER_SECRET = "";
    protected static String TWITTER_CALLBACK = "myapp://twitter";   

    protected static String stringToShare = "Hello World";  

    // connectors
    private static TwitterConnector twitter; 

    /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK)) {
            postTweet();
        }
        else {
            switch (bundle.getInt("service")) {

            case SERVICE_TWITTER:
                twitterAuth();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }           
        }
    }

    public void twitterAuth() {
      twitter = SocialNetworkHelper.createTwitterConnector(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET, TWITTER_CALLBACK);  
    }

    public void postTweet() {
        twitter.authorize(activity);
        twitter.tweet(stringToShare);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The from the activity (MainActivity) where I want to share from I call the following to launch the ShareActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShareActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("service", ShareActivity.SERVICE_TWITTER);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm using an Intent filter so that Twitter (oAuth) can callback to the calling activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>              
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="twitter" android:scheme="lifetime"/>
    </intent-filter>            
</activity>
```

**The flow:**

1. Use clicks the Share button on the MainActivity.
2. We call `startActivity(intent)` with the argument `intent` (ShareActivity).
3. `ShareActivity.onCreate()` is called and we start the Twitter oAuth authentication process.
4. The web browser activity is displayed and the user enters their Twitter credentials.
5. Twitter then displays a redirecting back to application page.
6. Twitter calls back to the URL `myapp://twitter`
7. The intent filter is triggered resulting in a new activity instance of ShareActivity being created and displayed.
8. ShareActivity then sends the Tweet to Twitter and the Tweet is successfully posted to the users wall.
9. ShareActivity then calls `finish()`

**Problem**

Everything works up until point 9. Calling `finish()` does not return to the original MainActivity it just closes the ShareActivity and returns to the browser activity showing the "Redirecting you back to the app" page.

If the user hits the back button they are taken back through all the Twitter auth pages and then eventually back to the MainActivity.

**What should happen**

When the Tweet is posted and we've finished with the ShareActivity the original MainActivity should be returned to (in it's original state).

ShareLib is handling all the auth and posting steps and I have no control on how it creates the new activities.

When I create my ShareActivity I've tried sending the Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with the idea that it would create a new activity stack but I don't know how to close all the activities in that stack and return to MainActivity.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this flag - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` in the intent when you launch the activity step 2.

or try using forwarding, a sample example is present in the android samples [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Forwarding.html)

Comment: I've already tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` but it seems to only stop the ShareActivity from being in the activity stack, all the Twitter auth steps are still in the activity stack and they are created be SocialLib.

Comment: okay, what about using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in step 2. It should clear the entire stack take you back to your 1st activity.

Comment: It seems that the SocialLib library is creating a new task. So when Twitter calls back a new instance ShareActivity is created in the new task. So I can't use any of the flags to resume previous activity because it's in the original task stack.

Comment: That was a major data point for debugging. Try declaring your activity with the flag - `singleTask` set. This ensures that if the activity has already been launched in before and it is in a different stack then that entire stack is brought into the foreground. Check the Figure 4 in the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and explanation.

Comment: if we use the flag - singleTask , then the intent data from the authentication page is not delivered to the activity..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.exit(0);`

Try it...

Comment: It just closes the ShareActivity and returns to the Browser Activity showing the "Redirect you back to application" twitter page.

Comment: System.exit(0) is a java call which goes directly to the VM, and should not be used on android. You have a handful of methods which will handle the stack propperly

Answer (score 0):

use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for intent. also when you call finish(). by using startActivity() give intent to mainactivity. also override onkeydown() function. check for backkey is pressed or not.

@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){


    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

there write a code to clear entire activity stack